# Как собрать историю запросов к GPS у приложения android?

Tags: android, gps

Есть приложение которое обращается к GPS. Хочу собрать историю обращения к локации этим приложением. Имею root доступ и доступ к shell root.
Каким способом можно собрать данные ?

Comment: можно в бд складировать  при каждом запросе или в файл какой-нибудь

Comment: @Andrew Я думаю автор имел ввиду не свое приложение